# Permissions for creating OAuth credentials in Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, permissions, google-cloud-platform

Using IAM, I am trying to allow certain users to access API's and allow them to create OAuth client credentials. Is there a predefined role for allowing this? I don't want to use the role of project editor, because I'm trying to allow access to only the necessary services.

It's when the user is in their project, and they go to "APIs and Services" > Credentials, the user receives this error:
You don't have permission to view API keys, OAuth clients, and service account keys.

Roles/Permissions:
-App Engine Admin
-Cloud Functions Developer
-Cloud Datastore Owner
-Service Account Admin
-Source Repository Administrator
-Storage Admin

Answer (score 5):

So I believe I've come across the solution. After failing to find a predefined role or any answers online, I started to delve into creating custom roles. If  anyone has issues with this in the future, here is what I have done.

I went to Project Settings > Roles > Create Role. I then created 2 custom Roles, here are all the permissions I assigned to them:

"Custom API"

- container.apiServices.create
- container.apiServices.delete
- container.apiServices.get
- container.apiServices.list
- container.apiServices.update
- container.apiServices.updateStatus
- serviceusage.apiKeys.create
- serviceusage.apiKeys.delete
- serviceusage.apiKeys.get
- serviceusage.apiKeys.getProjectForKey
- serviceusage.apiKeys.list
- serviceusage.apiKeys.regenerate
- serviceusage.apiKeys.revert
- serviceusage.apiKeys.update

"Custom Client Auth"

- clientauthconfig.brands.create
- clientauthconfig.brands.delete
- clientauthconfig.brands.get
- clientauthconfig.brands.list
- clientauthconfig.brands.update
- clientauthconfig.clients.create
- clientauthconfig.clients.createSecret
- clientauthconfig.clients.delete
- clientauthconfig.clients.get
- clientauthconfig.clients.getWithSecret
- clientauthconfig.clients.list
- clientauthconfig.clients.listWithSecrets
- clientauthconfig.clients.undelete
- clientauthconfig.clients.update

*Note that at the time of writing, these individual permissions are in a "testing" state, and may not work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the roles page:
[https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles?project=[your-project-id]](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles?project=%5Byour-project-id%5D)

And there you can filter for the permission you need:
[image]

Now you can see in the list all the roles include the permission you need, and you can return to the IAM page:
[https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=[your-project-id]](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=%5Byour-project-id%5D)

And select one of those rules:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google came up with a pre-defined role - "roles/oauthconfig.editor".

At the moment in Beta